# How secure is PasswordBox?

Tags: passwords, encryption, password-management

There is a fairly recent newcomer called [PasswordBox](http://www.passwordbox.com) on the market as a password manager.  I've read through their documentation, and although it sounds like it should be secure, I have been unable to find any impartial 3rd party reviews or vetting of their service.

Are there any 3rd party impartial reviewers who do this kind of validation?  Where can I find 3rd party reviews?  How can I properly vet their service?  Has anyone heard of this service and/or vetted their security?